# db value not getting added

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

**once i submit ,it returns back to my accept page but its not storing the values in the db**
**controller store function**

```
function store(){
  $this->validate($request,[
          'name'=>'required',
          'ppl'=>'required',
          'event' => 'required'
  ]);
   $user= new ppl();
   $user->name=$request->name;
   $user->ppl=$request->ppl;
   $user->event=$request->event;
   $user->save();
  return back();
}
```

**mode-ppl**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ppl extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
       'name','ppl','event'   ];
}
```

**db-ppls which has name,ppl,event**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ppls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->String('name');
            $table->integer('ppl');
            $table->String('event');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**blade-accept- it contains a form and "Route::post('/accept', [DetailController::class,'store']);
" -this is the route path**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="login-wrapper">
<form action="accept" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="Enter name">
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ppl">No of people:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="ppl"name="ppl" placeholder="no of people"  step="1">
</div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="event" name="event">
    @if(!empty($users))
    <label class="form-check-label" for="event">{{$users[0]->ename}}</label>
    @endIf
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style:"text-align:centre;">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Your `store` method of controller has no parameter called $request.

Comment: even then its not getting saved @QuynhXuanNguyen

Comment: Your checkbox has no value defined.

Comment: Are you sure? $request isn't passed to `store` method means it's similar to null and your request always fails validation rules. Btw, please print error messages to ensure request passes validation rules.

Comment: @QuynhXuanNguyen - i have included my error  message and change my **store** method. no error pops out                                                                                                  `  @if (count($errors) > 0)
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <strong>Sorry!</strong> Here have some issue please check<br><br>
      <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
  @endif
  @if(session('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('success') }}
  </div>
  @endif `

Comment: my checkbox take value from (`{{$users[0]->ename}}`) my database @parth

Comment: Please create a github repository to reproduce your problem and link it here!

Comment: @harithakannanraj `value=""` attribute is missing as i can see in your code. Please show `dd($request)` response.

Comment: i have added value to my attribute

Comment: https://github.com/Haritha-kannanraj/studio.git - @QuynhXuanNguyen

Comment: Please add seeder.

Answer (score 0):

The request may not pass validation rules but errors aren't displayed because of duplicate session. Please remove or comment `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` inside `$middlewareGroups` of `App\Http\Kernel.php`.

After doing this, you will see validation errors when submitting form. The rest of work is yours.

> You've already defined `StartSession` class inside `$middleware` to use `App\Http\Middleware\UserAuth`? I guess.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // more line...
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            // Remove or comment the line below
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, 
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
    // more line...
}
```

Comment: even after commenting the line am not getting any errors-@Quynh Xuan Nguyen

Comment: Please do not paste code to comment! It make no sense. I clone your repository, just do as I describe in my answer and errors are displayed. You can see an image in MR.

Comment: can u  please explain me how did u get  those error messages and how to use dd(); please am starting code it recently.please help!! @Quynh Xuan Nguyen.

Comment: Did you watch file changes at my PR on github? I just comment `StartSession:class` in 'web' middleware, then try submitting form.

Comment: I can't guess your problems. You should try installing and running code at https://github.com/seriquynh/studio/tree/fix_session_starts_twice. If errors aren't still displayed, I have no idea.